# Groupby and modify the records on array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, underscore.js

```
    const data = [
        {
        master_id: 1234,
        serial: 123455768769
    },
    {
        master_id: 1236,
        serial: 123455768799
    },
    {
        master_id: 1234,
        serial: 123455768779
    },
    {
        master_id: 1235,
        serial: 123455768789
    }
];
const serialNos = [123455768769, 123455768779,123455768789];

const expected = [{1234: [123455768769, 123455768779]}, {1235: [123455768789]}];

const result =  _.groupBy(data.filter(eachData => serialNos.includes(eachData.serial)), 'master_id');



console.log(result);
```

I am stuck after writing that much and not sure how to proceed further to achieve the expected output.

Logic:
Filter the `data` based on `serialNos` and then group by them using master_id and modify them like the expected output. I am stuck on the 3rd that modification part.

I am using typescript and underscore js in my project .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could chain the sequence and get first a subset and then after grouping map the wanted property.

```js
const
    data = [{ master_id: 1234, serial: 123455768769 }, { master_id: 1236, serial: 123455768799 }, { master_id: 1234, serial: 123455768779 }, { master_id: 1235, serial: 123455768789 }]
    serialNos = [123455768769, 123455768779, 123455768789],
    result = _
        .chain(data)
        .filter(eachData => serialNos.includes(eachData.serial))
        .groupBy('master_id')
        .map((array, key) => ({ [key]: _.map(array, _.property('serial')) }))
        .value();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```